# My first xcode view controller does not act like the others

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, controller

Here I Have This Picture:

[image]

It shows me being able to drag the button into `viewcontroller.swift` Using the first `rootViewController`.

Next View This Picture:

[image]

This Picture shows me not being able to drag the other button into `viewcontroller.swift` using my 3rd View Controller.

I don't know how to fix it. I Need Help!

Comment: Do not repost your questions.

Comment: You will need another class to handle the second viewcontroller